# How to insert data into SQL table in Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I want to insert data into sql table in silverlight application.
I know how to use WCF Ria services to show data from sql table into datagrid tool.

But now i want to add some data into table using Silverlight application?

I tried LINQ to SQL to method which uses web service to insert data.

So now my question is it okay to insert data in sql using LINQ to SQL method and fetch and operate on the same data using WCF Ria Services ?

Means using both the techniques along side ?

Please suggest
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find good example : [WCF RIA Services Part 3: Updating Data](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-3-Updating-Data.aspx) which help you to complete the task easily...